# Salesforce creating incorrect HMAC SHA1 value

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, hmacsha1

I'm trying to generate an HMAC value within Salesforce using the Crypto generateMac function, but the result doesn't match with other utilities.

For example, I'm trying to hash the value `Hash me` using the key `ac67ad3b8771bf63d4fa9582845a18f921514f36`. I'm expecting the result to be `66fe419859ac42ad88354dfa52f2196a26d767e1`, but it's actually `7d1f56c728dfefdcb9edb72b7c0c8df2acf1cae9`.

My apex code is:

```
Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HMacSHA1', Blob.valueOf('Hash me'),
    Blob.valueOf('33a1211c0ee01511ccba1e456bb95503')); 
string hasedValue = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(mac);
```

I'm guessing the issue is related to converting to/from binary or maybe related to case, but I cannot match the expected result.

My expected result is based on the result from http://hash.online-convert.com/sha1-generator and a couple other online HMAC calculators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other option is to do a base 64 encode:

```
EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);
```

I'd be surprised if generateMac + convertToHex aren't working for you. They've always worked for me. I'm sure you've looked, but just in case I'd go over the Amazon web services example in the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm?CSHID=apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm).

Comment: I took out the space in "Hash me", and I'm able to match the output between apex and other sources. My app doesn't actually need spaces, so I can live with it for now. Thanks for verifying I was doing it correctly, though :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. It's unsettling when black box methods aren't functioning properly, especially in Apex, since writing your own Crypto class isn't an option.